# FTP server on Mavericks desktop

Tags: macos, logs, ftp

I was thinking of installing vsftp through homebrew but found that OS X has its own version of ftpd. So I started to use this server and works fine, except for some security issues. I'm looking for the log file and cannot find it. I've been looking for it on the web and there is a way to configure the logging but just for OS X Panther.

Do you know were this file is located or how to configure ftp for handling log files?

Answer (score 1):

Most unix processes write to or use a call to syslog. You can see this in Console.app entries be default (if none has reconfigured syslog) will show up in Al Messages and in /var/logs/system.log

You can increase the logging level by providing the -d argument to the ftp command line